# jQuery scrolltop goes to bottom of page first

Tags: jquery

When i click the anchor tag,  the scrollbar goes directly to the bottom of the page and then proceeds to the desired position.  It should go straight to the element `$(".accordion-title[data-name='" + name + "']")`

```
$(".cast-roles a").click(function(event) {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");

    event.preventDefault();

    var scrollval =  $(".accordion-title[data-name='" + name + "']").offset().top - 100;

    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop:scrollval},1000);
    });
});
```

I don't see where i went wrong.  How do i solve?

Comment: I just tried your codes in my snippet, it seems working fine (go straight to the desired position). can you post out your html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the snippet below it's working fine

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cast-roles a").click(function(event) {
      var name = $(this).attr("data-name");

      event.preventDefault();

      var scrollval =  $(".accordion-title[data-name='" + name + "']").offset().top - 100;

      $("html,body").animate({
          scrollTop:scrollval},1000);
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion-title{
  height : 500px;
  width : 100vw;
  background-color : #000;
  color : #FFF;
  margin-top : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cast-roles">
  <a data-name="redirection">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-title" data-name="redirection">
  Test
</div>
```

I just saw an error but I think you just forgot to put this line when you have copied then pasted

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

In your code you closed the document ready function but didn't write it on top of your JS code

```
$(".cast-roles a").click(function(event) {
var name = $(this).attr("data-name");

event.preventDefault();

var scrollval =  $(".accordion-title[data-name='" + name + "']").offset().top - 100;

$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop:scrollval},1000);
***});***
});
```

Sorry if my English is bad and good luck, wish I helped you